# Error during make install of opensips cachedb_redis on RedHat

Tags: linux, redis, opensips

I am facing error while make install of opensips.

please help me resolve this. I already installed Redis and freeradius.

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/aaa_radius'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/aaa_radius'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/aaa_radius'
Compiling aaa_radius.c
Compiling rad.c
Linking aaa_radius.so
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/aaa_radius'


make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/cachedb_redis'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/cachedb_redis'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/cachedb_redis'
Compiling cachedb_redis.c
In file included from cachedb_redis.c:41:
cachedb_redis_dbase.h:29:29: error: hiredis/hiredis.h: No such file or directory
In file included from cachedb_redis.c:41:
cachedb_redis_dbase.h:38: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘redisContext’
make[1]: *** [cachedb_redis.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/cachedb_redis'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% confident redis development packages can be found in the `epel` repository (`/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`):

`yum install hiredis-devel.x86_64`

Now, if you really want to install Red Hat-only packages, you should try to enable as many repositories as you can from `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` until you hopefully find a good one!

Comment: I dont have redhat registered thats why i am using epel

Comment: could you mark this as "chosen answer"? Maybe it will help some other users in the future

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by installing hiredis-devel.x86_64.

but now i am having this error.

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/json'
Compiling array_del.c
array_del.c:29:23: error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
array_del.c:30:38: error: json/json_object_private.h: No such file or directory
array_del.c:32: warning: ‘struct array_list’ declared inside parameter list
array_del.c:32: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
array_del.c: In function ‘array_list_del_idx’:
array_del.c:36: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
array_del.c:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
array_del.c:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
array_del.c:41: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
array_del.c:43: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
array_del.c:44: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
array_del.c:44: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
array_del.c: At top level:
array_del.c:47: warning: ‘struct json_object’ declared inside parameter list
array_del.c: In function ‘json_object_array_del’:
array_del.c:49: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make[1]: *** [array_del.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/opensips-1.9.0-tls/modules/json'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: `yum install json-c-devel`